# Failure activating Enterprise features

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Using Central Administration in the highest elevated account we have still causes the activation to fail for Enterprise features however no error is given other than to check the logs but it is not clear which logs its referring to.

Looking in both ULS logs and Windows log the only error I could find that provided any information is as follows:
My amateur hunch is that I have some kind of timer thing to attend to. but I am very unclear.

---

**The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Administration.SkuUpgradeJob (ID 67bc4ca6-2aaa-4729-854e-2338c2603de5) threw an exception. More information is included below.
Post setup configuration failed when attempting post setup configuration task -cmd services -install -cmd installfeatures**

Answer (score 0):

Changing the account for the Timer Service in Administrative Tools -> Services to the machine account allows me to install Enterprise edition. 
I am unclear why this would be a required step for installing Enterprise Edition and why its not documented if the account that is normally by default for the timer jobs are not elevated enough to install Enterprise Edition.

If improper accounts for installing Enterprise are the default for timer jobs then Microsoft needs to document this given the error messages do not hint at it.